# Deleting a line from txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file with lists of names like this

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

I want to delete the line with "Name2" in it, if Name2 is in the list. I got this code:

```
f = open(list,'r')
    if("Name2" in f.read().splitlines()):
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        f = open(badhumanslist, "w")
        for line in lines:
            if line != "Name2" + "\n":
                f.write(line)
        f.close()
```

The problem is that this code empties the whole file. I don't see my error, it should rewrite all the lines, except the one with "Name2"

Answer (score 2):

You already read the whole file in line 2: `f.read()`. Then, `lines = f.readlines()` returns an empty list.

```
def read_all():
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        return file.read()
content = read_all()
lines = content.splitlines()
if "Name2\n" in lines:
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        for line in lines:
            if line != "Name2\n":
                file.write(line)
```